# Embed HP Dialogue Live Editor in Internet Explorer

Tags: internet-explorer, activex, hp-exstream

I am trying to embed the HP Dialogue Live Editor into an existing web page but I am struggling to determine what format the `object` tag needs to take. The current format of my `object` tag is shown:

```
<object classid="clsid:2D9B8B8C-B00A-474A-90B8-900737D6A7F3" width="800" height="600" type="application/dlf" data="http://localhost:19897/dlf.dlf">
</object>
```

When I run this page in Internet Explorer the live editor is not visible and there is also no indication that the control couldn't load (there is no small box with the red X inside).

As an aside, if I link directly to the DLF file (`<a href="http://localhost:19897/dlf.dlf">A DLF File</a>`), when I click on the link it also doesn't load the live editor (I just see a small box with a red X inside).  I have used fiddler and I can see that the content of the DLF file has downloaded.

The only way I've had the live editor loading correctly in Internet Explorer so far is by dragging the DLF file and dropping it onto IE.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After some further investigation with fiddler I was able to determine that the problem with the DLF link not working was due to a mime type issue.  By default the file was being returned with a mime type of `application/octet-stream`.  I updated my web.config and adding the following:

```
<system.webServer>
  <staticContent>
    <mimeMap fileExtension=".dlf" mimeType="application/dlf"/>
  </staticContent>
</system.webServer>
```

After doing this the correct mime type (`application/dlf`) was returned and clicking the link opened the file in the editor as expected.

Once I had this working I then went back to trying to embed the editor into an existing page.  I am still unable to do this with an `object` or `embed` tag however I am able to do this with an `iframe`.